# laravel 5.4 ErrorException

Tags: php, laravel

Есть на сайте авторизация через соц сети. Через гугл все проходит нормально, но через фейсбук выдает эту ошибку,

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 294 and defined

вот код файлов для авторизации

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Provider;

class SocialAccountService
{
public function createOrGetUser(Provider $provider)
{

    $providerUser = $provider->user();
    $providerName = class_basename($provider);

    $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider($providerName)
        ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
        ->first();

    if ($account) {
        return $account->user;
    } else {

        $account = new SocialAccount([
            'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
            'provider' => $providerName
        ]);

        $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

        if (!$user) {

            $user = User::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
            ]);
            return $user;
        }

        $account->user()->associate($user);
        $account->save();

        return $user;

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

По ошибке видно, что метод `createOrGetUser()` возвращает null, а метод `login()` ждет объект созданного пользователя, то есть нужно отловить место в котором у вас не возвращается объект юзера.

Comment: это я понял, не подскажите где ошибка та эта, просто до недавнего времени все работало, а потом бах и такая ошибка, при чем только на фейсбуке

Comment: так не скажешь, нужно отладку кода делать во время авторизации через фейсбук, но по коду получается у тебя нет в одном месте проверки: $user = User::create([ ... , то есть у тебя тут может быть так, что пользователь не создался и $user у тебя пустой, в итоге и return будет таким же. Попробуй к примеру в логи записать $user в этом участке кода и посмотри, вдруг он пуст